# Keeping matched rows from several columns in excel

Tags: r, excel

My dataset contains information on coverage of three different types of vaccinations across countries:

[image: Unfortunately I can't attach a screenshot]

For comparison, I want to keep only those countries that have data on all three types of vaccines. I tried several methods (VLOOKUP in Excel, left join in R) but none gave the desired results. Please advise if you know any solution to this using Excel or R.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please provide reproducible example otherwise it is tough to understand the problem

Comment: Here is a glimpse of the dataset: 

Country vacc1 Country vacc2 Country vacc3 //


Afghanistan 0.30 Afghanistan 0.50 Afghanistan 2.45 //

Armenia 2.80      Armenia 3.90      Lebanon 0.93  // 
Azerbaijan 4.70      Azerbaijan 1.08      Bahrain 0.94 //

Lao PDR 1.50     Bahrain 8.20 Bangladesh 0.39

Comment: can you please dput in r or send screenshot of your excel sheet

Comment: The screenshot was attached as hyperlinked sentence (Unfortunately I can't attach a screenshot) under the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Try nested `dplyr::inner_join()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "Country    vacc1   Country.1   vacc2   Country.2   vacc3
Afghanistan 0.30 Afghanistan    0.50    Afghanistan 2.45
Armenia 2.80    Armenia 3.90    Lebanon 0.93
Azerbaijan  4.70 Azerbaijan 1.08 Bahrain    0.94
Lao_PDR 1.50    Bahrain 8.20 Bangladesh 0.39", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

inner_join(df[,1:2], df[,3:4], by = c("Country" = "Country.1")) %>%
  inner_join(df[,5:6], by = c("Country" = "Country.2"))

#       Country vacc1 vacc2 vacc3
# 1 Afghanistan   0.3   0.5  2.45
```

Keep in mind that R won't allow duplicated column names, so check how it's handling the multiple Country columns.

Comment: Thanks a Zillion Paul))) Exactly what I was looking for. Sorry about the poor phrasing of the question that it had to be downvoted, but I'm sure this code will now make life easier for many.

Comment: Hi Paul, I've been trying to revise the code for five different variables (vaccines), but not being able to do so. Could you please let me know if its possible, with the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question (then add the link here so I can find it easily), keep in mind these points on asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In R:
Supose you've imported the file into a variable called `data` (with `read.xls()` or similar). Use this:

```
noNAsIndices <- !is.na(data[[2]]) | is.na(data[[4]]) | is.na(data[[6]])
data <- data[which(noNAsIndices), ]
```

Comment: This works if the empty values from the dataset in Excel are empty, i.e. parsed as `NA` in R.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm interpreting this correctly, but if a country appears in a row three times, that means it has data on each vaccine type like rows 1, 11, and 15? If so, you can use a formula like this one:

```
=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(A2,E:E,1,FALSE),"it's in all three columns"),"it's not")
```

and copy it down. Obviously you'll change those text strings to something more usable that R could identify.